# Update Spark Inferred DataFrame schema with pre-defined schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pre-defined schema (base schema) for the incoming dataset. But in some cases the dataset might have a slightly different schema with some additional columns or nested column fields.
While processing the data I want to use the combined schema (base schema + inferred schema) so that all the columns/fields are considered. I am following the below approach for now. I wanted to know if there is any better/faster way to achieve this.

```
StructType predefinedSchema = (StructType) DataType.fromJson(predefinedSchemaJsonString);
Dataset<Row> dfWithInferredSchema = spark.read().json(incomingDatasetPath);
spark.createDataFrame(dfWithInferredSchema.rdd(), predefinedSchema.merge(dfWithInferredSchema.schema()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are interoping between dataset, rdd and back to dataset. I'm not sure, but it might have an impact. You could avoid it by just merging schemas and then create dataset with merged schema:

```
StructType predefinedSchema = (StructType) DataType.fromJson(predefinedSchemaJsonString);
StructType inferredSchema = spark.read().json(incomingDatasetPath).schema();
StructType mergedSchema = predefinedSchema.merge(inferredSchema);

Dataset<Row> dfWithMergedSchema = spark.read().schema(mergedSchema).json(incomingDatasetPath);
```

Comment: Earlier I tried this approach only but this will also have performance impact as we are reading the dataset twice (first to infer the schema and then reading with merged schema).

Comment: Makes sense, with json. I usually work with parquet, so spark can only infer schema without actually reading the data. Perhaps with json, assuming all parts have same schema, you can infer schema by only reading one part. Or, better, if you have an option doing so, when saving the json data, save also the schema as separate file, and use it when reading